# What's the right combination for the Stonehenge like formation?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at a Stonehenge like formation and I need to solve a puzzle similar to one we encountered earlier.

How can I find the right combination?

[image]

Comment: I did not came here for the moment, but usually you can find the symbol pattern somewhere.

Comment: Can you describe the location of the monument? Did you arrive there for a quest, or did you just happen upon it?

Comment: I found a stonehenge like this - there were marked tablets around the edges of the menhirs. Is it next to a hatch that doesn't lead to a dungeon but does lead to a Destruction Skillbook?

Comment: Yes that's the one @RavenDreamer

Comment: Where is this located on the map? Can you give us the coordinates?

Comment: I just brute-forced it. It's not like there are many possible combinations.

Comment: do you want the correct combination as your question title says or do you want to know how it's figured out as per what your question body says. if the latter then none of the answers answer the question (they give the combination, now how to find the right combination)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From left to right, with the switch facing the gate which needs to be opened:

> Dolphin, Hawk, and Snake

Then, activate the switch.

Answer (score 5):

If you are at the switch facing the grate which needs to be opened from left to right it is  (hidden behind a spoiler if you don't want to know)

> fish hawk snake

Answer (score -4):

The Correct Combination from Left to Right is Hawk Hawk Snake[image]

Comment: This is AKA Barleydark Farm Puzzle :)

Comment: This goes against what the other two answers say...

Comment: @Vemonus Agreed. This is obviously due to the slightly different orientation of this image. The pattern correct, but only if you look at it from this angle, and obviously, the stone of the left marked hawk is not the forward direction for the stone. The side facing the center is the dolphin (which changing hawk to dolphin causes it to match the other answers), and other images do show the hawk on this side.